# What is the main window of an applet called and how do you refer to it?

Tags: java, applet, gstreamer

I'm trying to use Xoverlay and call setWindowHandle, but I need to give a component. When I do "run as applet" in eclipse, eclipse creates a small window with the appletviewer. I want to know how to get a reference to that window. I can see that they are adding elements to it here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html

They are simply using add to add it to the main window. Right now in my application, another window is being spawned that displays video, and I want that video to be displayed in the main applet window so that I can embed the applet in an HTML page and have full control over the window.

I've tried using 'root pane', but then I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component must be a native window
```

EDIT: By request, here is my code (There is a comment at the line in question):

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.swing.*;

import org.gstreamer.*;
import org.gstreamer.elements.PlayBin2;
import org.gstreamer.interfaces.XOverlay;
import org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GstXOverlayAPI;

public class VideoPlayer extends JApplet {
    public void init() {
        Gst.init();
        final PlayBin2 playbin = new PlayBin2("VideoPlayer");
        URI uri = null;
        try 
        {
            uri = new URI("udp://239.1.1.1:51002");
        } 
        catch (URISyntaxException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        playbin.setURI(uri);
        //System.setProperty("apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz", "false"); 
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Element videosink = ElementFactory.make("xvimagesink", "imagesink");
                    videosink.set("qos", "false");
                    videosink.set("sync", "false");
                    playbin.setVideoSink(videosink);
                    playbin.setState(State.PLAYING);
                    XOverlay.wrap(videosink).setWindowHandle(rootPane); // I need the handle to the main window here
                }
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Gst.main();
        playbin.setState(State.NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: No code makes this tough to answer with confidence.  Consider creating an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I don't understand what I need to provide code for. This is just a conceptual question. I can't really provide an SSCCE because the whole reason I'm asking this is because these aren't Swing elements I'm adding. That's why I need to know the reference to the main window. I will edit my post to include my code though, although I'm unsure how that will help.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the "main window" you're supposed to access in an applet is the Applet/JApplet object itself. You could try using `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor()` but it's possible the Applet just can't access the native window hosting it because it's outside the control of the JRE.

Answer (score 1):

try using `getRootPane()` or switch from JApplet to Applet and use `getParent()`

```
XOverlay.wrap(videosink).setWindowHandle(getRootPane()|getParent());
```

Comment: This didn't work either. I ultimately ended up storing what "this" points to at the beginning of the method, and then using that in setWindowHandle.